# useState() losing the state(data) on refresh when the data is coming from redux store

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, redux-observable, react-table-v7

I am having a weird issue that makes the data set to undefined. I am implementing react-table (one with hooks). If I use one from the example of react-table, they make use makedata.js & their code is below

```
const [data, setData] = useState(useMemo(() => makeData(20), []) );
```

But my code just replaces makeData with my data that is coming from redux after API call.

```
//For setting data
useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser || !savedProjectId) {
      alert("Please Select A Project");
      return;
    }
    listenToProjectData(currentUser.clientId, savedProjectId);
  }, [currentUser, savedProjectId, listenToGuests]);

// For setting state

 const [data, setData] = useState(
    useMemo(() => projectData, [projectData, loading])
  );
```

So when we make a change in code, react renders and data is coming fine, i.e `data` is not undefined. It's the same when we go to other page and navigate back to it.
The moment we refresh the page, `data` is undefined.

P.S. projectData is not undefined, only, in the beginning, momentarily it is but then the data updates in it but it is not reflected in our state of `data` & refresh makes the `data` undefined though we are using useMemo.